# Automate junk software removal

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have a pc that I use for testing things that I frequently wipe and re-install using the restore cd that came with it.  Unfortunately, the install cd puts a lot of junk on the machine.  Sometimes I just live with it, since I know I'll be wiping soon again anyway, but I really want to be able to remove this junk in a simple way.  My long term solution is to be able to use a virtual machine instead, but that's not an option right now.

So what I want to is put together a small batch file (or even vbs script) to uninstall this stuff that I can run after a restore.  It's the same set of programs each time, so tailoring the script to the programs is not a problem.

What is a problem is finding the uninstall programs for some of this junk.  In several cases, the only way I can find to uninstall them is via the Add/Remove programs entry in the control panel.  So what I'm looking for is a way to pull that in from the control panel in my script/batch file.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I did consider asking this on StackOverflow because it's for a script, but I have a strong suspicion that if I asked there it would be moved here, because it's really more a systems administration/windows issue as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity why isn't the virtual machine an option? It would probably work nicely if you have a white box that is capable of running VMWare ESXi.

Comment: Two reasons: **1)** licensing -- I don't want to buy an extra xp license for the host and I don't want to install a linux host. **2)** performance -- It's an older machine that would definitely suffer for the extra layer of software

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Wmic Command

1. Open a command prompt.
2. Input **`WMIC`** and press Return. You will see a prompt that looks like this: `wmic:root\cli>`
3. At the new prompt, execute the following command: **`product get name`**
   This will generate a list of installed applications.
4. At the prompt, execute the following command: **`product where name="" call uninstall`**
   where application name is the name of the program you wish to uninstall (use the exact name provided by the previously generated list).
   For example, if I were wanting to uninstall Adobe Reader 9, my command would look like this:
   product where name="Adobe Reader 9" call uninstall
5. When prompted, input y to **confirm** that you wish to uninstall the application and press **Return**.

The application will be uninstalled.

source: [tech-receipes](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2947/windows_uninstall_application_command_line/)

You could call the command directly: **`wmic product where name="" call uninstall /interactive:off`**

[MSDN about the wmic command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531%28VS.85%29.aspx)

#### [The PC Decrapifier](http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/)

A program designed to remove or uninstall a specific list of unwanted software in an unattended fashion.
It can be used to clean off most of the annoying software that is typically shipped with new PCs.

The commercial version has the additional ability to automate itself. If you would like to include the PC Decrapifier in another script, you can pass additional parameters on the command line.

#### [Tarma Uninstall](http://www.tarma.com/support/uninstall.htm)

Uninstalls a program from the command line (i.e., without going through the Add/Remove Programs control panel). It can also list information about installed programs. This program can be used in batch files and as a custom action in installers.

Comment: The wmic command didn't work as well as I would have hoped.  I still have to remove some things manually and others were only half removed.  But I was able to remove a few of the items like this.

Comment: When I try this command, it prompts me to type Y or N to uninstall. Is there anyway to get rid of the prompt? I am using the /interactive:off option too, but it still is prompting me.

Comment: Figured it out, you have to use /nointeractive instead of /interactive:off

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just tidy up a fresh system restore and then clone the disk yourself (e.g. with **[EASEUS ToDo Backup](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/)**). Even if you can automate the cleanup process, it will take significantly longer to restore a system from DVD and remove the junk than deploying a clean disk image.

Or even better, since this is Windows XP, most restore disks contain the installation source, usually in a folder called i386, just create your own XP installation disk and install XP clean from scratch and then clone the disk. no matter how automated your uninstaller script, there will still be a ton  of junk files and orphaned registry entries left.

Here's a tutorial for you:

[How to Create a Bootable Windows XP Setup Disk on a Preinstalled / Preloaded Windows System](http://www.howtohaven.com/system/createwindowssetupdisk.shtml)

Comment: I considered that, and it's a good idea.  But I think this time I really want to build script to clean up the junk.